# elasticsearch field mapping affects acorss different types in same index

Tags: elasticsearch

I was told that "Every type has its own mapping, or schema definition" at [the official guide](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/mapping-intro.html).

But the fact I've met is the mapping can affect other types within the same index. Here is the situation:

Mapping definition:

```
[root@localhost agent]# curl localhost:9200/agent*/_mapping?pretty
{
  "agent_data" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "host" : {
        "_all" : {
          "enabled" : false
        },
        "properties" : {
          "ip" : {
            "type" : "ip"
          },
          "node" : {
            "type" : "string",
            "index" : "not_analyzed"
          }
        }
      },
      "vul" : {
        "_all" : {
          "enabled" : false
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and then I index a record:

```
[root@localhost agent]# curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/agent_data/vul?pretty' -d '{"ip": "1.1.1.1"}'
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [ {
      "type" : "mapper_parsing_exception",
      "reason" : "failed to parse [ip]"
    } ],
    "type" : "mapper_parsing_exception",
    "reason" : "failed to parse [ip]",
    "caused_by" : {
      "type" : "number_format_exception",
      "reason" : "For input string: \"1.1.1.1\""
    }
  },
  "status" : 400
}
```

Seems that it tries to parse the ip as a number. So I put a number in this field:

```
[root@localhost agent]# curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/agent_data/vul?pretty' -d '{"ip": "1123"}'
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [ {
      "type" : "remote_transport_exception",
      "reason" : "[Argus][127.0.0.1:9300][indices:data/write/index[p]]"
    } ],
    "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
    "reason" : "mapper [ip] cannot be changed from type [ip] to [long]"
  },
  "status" : 400
}
```

This problem goes away if I explicitly define the ip field of vul type as ip field-type.

I don't quite understand the behavior above. Do I miss something?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement

> Every type has its own mapping, or schema definition

is true. But this is not complete information.
There may be conflicts between different types with the same field within one index.

[Mapping - field conflicts](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping.html#field-conflicts)

> Mapping types are used to group fields, **but the fields in each
>   mapping  type are not independent of each other**. Fields with:
>
> - the same name
> - in the same index
> - in different mapping types
>
> map to the same field internally, and must have the same mapping. If a
>   `title` field exists in both the `user` and `blogpost` mapping types, the
>   `title` fields must have exactly the same mapping in each type. The only
>   exceptions to this rule are the `copy_to`, `dynamic`, `enabled`,
>   `ignore_above`, `include_in_all`, and `properties` parameters, which may
>   have different settings per field.